# How can I compile stylesheets dynamically in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am aware of the method for Rails 3(http://www.krautcomputing.com/blog/2012/03/27/how-to-compile-custom-sass-stylesheets-dynamically-during-runtime/), but it does not work in rails4.

Has anyone achieved this in Rails4